# Protractor & Jasmine Configuration on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jasmine, protractor, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure Protractor on Jenkins for CTI.... I have already setup Protractor along with Jasmine and trying to get it integrated with Jenkins.

I have gone through several links & blogs on internet but none seem to be helpful in providing detailed information on how to get the Protractor configured with Jenkins.

Any help or pointing towards the right blog or video will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please give us more information? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

@Vishal

Please find the below snippet you can add as grunt task.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        exec: {
            protractorRunAppsTest: {
                cmd: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\cli.js C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\test\\conf.js'
                }
        },
        server: {
            port:3000,
            base: ['app']
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect'); 
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

    grunt.registerTask('server', 'Start node server', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('Started server on port 3000');
        require('./app.js');
    });
    grunt.registerTask('runAppsTest', ['exec:protractorRunAppsTest']);

};
```

Save the above code as Gruntfile.js

Make sure this is in the workspace folder for jenkins.

In Jenkins job add the 'Build' Section (i am assuming Jenkins is windows server)

add "Execute Windows Batch Command" and add the below content to the text field there.

```
cd %WORKSPACE%
grunt server runAppsData || exit 0
```

I hope this would work for you. Please try and let me know. 
Consider rating my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the above information. I need to run the Protractor tests via Jenkins to Git and not the windows server, Will the grunt work in this scenario or a different setup is required for the same.

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal try to use grunt for doing the same. So that you can easily integrate the Jenkins job with grunt task details.

Just configure and register task with grunt.
Then use the grunt task to run in jenkins.

If you want i can provide more details.

Comment: yes please provide me the information if you have it handy. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Any way i have posted new answer.