# Looking for a good tool to run Protractor automations automatically

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, automation, protractor

as a QA man  I build my automation using Protractor (a language that works on AngularJS).
Right now to run the automation, I run it manually and do a simple "Run" threw the software.
I'd like to start running the automation automatically - run it through the night for example, and by the morning - getting detailed reports.

I read about some relevant tools, and right now the most appropriate tool I found is Jenkins.
However, I would also like to hear from you and people who understand a bit about this.
Do you know another tool and in even better quality?
And if not, I'd be happy if you'll send me anyway relevant materials about Jenkins (installation, how to run / run, etc ...).

Thanks and have a nice weekend :)

Comment: TFS or VSTS works great for this. Jenkins will do the trick too. You can find more info on Jenkins here https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/. And for VSTS just create a free account here https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/

Comment: So if you use Jenkins, I wrote something on it. https://medium.com/@cnishina/protractor-in-ci-jenkins-6f5fd3fc06ee You do not need to set of Xvfb if you use chromedriver headless. If you decide to go the circle ci route, you can do something similar to how Protractor uses it. See https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/circle.yml If you want detailed reports, check out https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/jasmine-junit-reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Continuous Integration/Delivery Software will work for you.

Several are Jenkins, Jetbrains' Teamcity, Atlassian's Bamboo, Microsoft TFS.

I would recommend Jenkins since it will let you do more customization as well as open source, means it is free to use. But to setup you would require initially more work.

You can see good documentation here for Jenkins too https://jenkins.io/doc/
If you have more budget, then I would suggest your TeamCity or TFS.

I would say this question is not related in the protractor section too. It is more like how you are going to improve your CI/CD or build automation for your QA project.

If you really want something for building the QA run for the Jenkins or any CI, I would recommend to run the job as

> grunt task

Please find how to do that in the below link 
[Protractor & Jasmine Configuration on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157923/protractor-jasmine-configuration-on-jenkins/42387969#42387969)

If you want, I can give you more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) It would be delightful if you can send me more information about that subject. I've tried to intergrate between Jenkins and Protractor, and didn't understand how should it work and what are the steps.

Comment: i have provided the link in the above answer, have you tried it? you have to install the grunt using   " npm install -g grunt "  . Dont use the 'use srtict' which i have mentioned there it is for the lower versions of protractor and node. If you are using the latest one it is good to use without 'use strict'